# dplyr, rlang: Unable to predict if minor varients of passing names to nested dplyr functions will work

Tags: r, quote, rlang, non-standard-evaluation

Data for reproducibility

```
.i <- tibble(a=2*1:4+1, b=2*1:4)
```

This function is supposed to take its data and other arguments as unquoted names, find those names in the data, and use them to add a column and filter out the 
top row. It does not work. Mutate says it can not find a.

```
t1 <- function(.j=.i, X=a, Y=b){
  e_X <- enquo(X)
  e_Y <- enquo(Y)
  mutate(.data=.j, pass=UQ(e_X)+1) %>% 
    filter(UQ(e_Y) > 3) -> out
  out
}
t1(a,b)
```

This function, which I found by typo -- note the .i instead of .j in the mutate statement -- does what the previous function was supposed to do. And I don't know why. I think it is skipping over the function arguments and finding .i in the global environment. Or maybe it is using a ouiji board.

```
t2 <- function(.j=.i, X=a, Y=b){
  e_X <- enquo(X)
  e_Y <- enquo(Y)
  mutate(.data=.i, pass=UQ(e_X)+1) %>% 
  filter(UQ(e_Y) > 3) -> out
  out
}
t1(a,b)
```

Since mutate could not find .j when passed to it in the usual R way, maybe it needs to be passed in an rlang-style quosure, like the formals X and Y. This function also does not work, with UQ in mutate saying that it can not find a. Like the first function above, it works if the .j in mutate is replaced with a .i. (Seems like there should be an "enquos" to parallel quos).

```
t3 <- function(.j=.i, X=a, Y=b){
  e_j <- enquo(.j)
  e_X <- enquo(X)
  e_Y <- enquo(Y)
  mutate(.data=UQ(.j), pass=UQ(e_X)+1) %>% 
    filter(UQ(e_Y) > 3) -> out
  out
}
t1(a,b)
```

Finally, it appears that, once the .i substitution in mutate is made, t4() no longer needs a data argument at all. See below, where I replace it with bop_foo_foo. If, however, you replace bop_foo_foo throughout with the name of the data, .i, (t5()) then UQ again fails to find a.

```
bop_foo_foo <- 0
t4 <- function(bop_foo_foo, X=a, Y=b){
  e_j <- enquo(bop_foo_foo)
  e_X <- enquo(X)
  e_Y <- enquo(Y)
  mutate(.data=UQ(.i), pass=UQ(e_X)+1) %>% 
    filter(UQ(e_Y) > 3) -> out
  out
}
t1(a,b)
```

The functions above seem to me to be relatively minor variants on a single  function. I have run dozens more, and although I have observed some patterns,
and read the enquo and UQ help files I do not know how many times, a real 
understanding continues to elude me.

I would like to know why the functions above that that don't work don't, and why the ones that do work do. I don't necessarily need a function by function critique. If you can state general principles that embody the required, understanding, that would be delightful. And more than sufficient.

Comment: At least, you have `.i` in global environment which is used, if there is no `.i` variable in local environment.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion as to how positional vs named arguments are treated in standard R function calls (unrelated to `rlang`). What do you expect `t1(a,b)` to be or to do? Because it's equivalent to `t1(.j = a, X = b, Y = b)` (unnamed arguments are positional) while I suspect you expect it to be `t1(.j = .i, X = a, Y = b)` (which it is not).

Comment: Or did you mean to type `.i %>% t1(a, b)` maybe?

Comment: @Aurèle In your first comment above you are absolutely correct. I keep trying to match arguments by the argument name, and forgetting that R only pays attention to the names of arguments to the left of the = for matching and to the right of an = for scoping outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is skipping over the function arguments and finding .i in the global environment.

Yes, scope of symbols in R is hierarchical. The variables local to a function are looked up first, and then the surrounding environment of the function is inspected, and so on.

> mutate(.data = UQ(.j), ...)

I think you are missing the difference between regular arguments and (quasi)quoted arguments. Unquoting is only relevant for quasiquoted arguments. Since the `.data` argument of `mutate()` is not quasiquoted it does not make sense to try and unquote stuff. The quasiquoted arguments are the ones that are captured/quoted with `enexpr()` or `enquo()`. You can tell whether an argument is quasiquoted either by looking at the documentation or by recognising that the argument supports direct references to columns (regular arguments need to be explicit about where to find the columns).

In the next version of rlang, the exported `UQ()` function will throw an error to make it clear that it should not be called directly and that it can only be used in quasiquoted arguments.

I would suggest:

- Call the first argument of your function `data` or `df` rather than `.i`.
- Don't give it a default. The user should always supply the data.
- Don't capture it with `enquo()` or `enexpr()` or `substitute()`. Instead pass it directly to the data argument of other verbs.

Once this is out of the way it will be easier to work out the rest.

Comment: Thanks, lionel! I don't think this quite gets me there. I am trying to create an outer function taking the _names_ of a data set and some columns in it. I want the user to tell me the names of variables that play certain roles, like weights and grouping variables Then I do thing with the variables based on their roles (as, e.g. weights). I hoped I could do this with by quasiquoting the names with enquo, and I still think that should be possible, but now I am thinking I would be better off using strings instead.